# Remove object from three js scene by selecting it

Tags: javascript, three.js

My three js scene contains many OBJ models, some of which are preloaded with the scene, some of which are added to the scene via button click.

A user of my application may add an object but then decide to remove it. I am trying to figure out how to this but need guidance.

Ideally I would do this my holding shift and clicking the object to delete, or by adding the object to a group with shift + select and then deleting with a keyboard press (similar to the grouping here: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=drag#misc_controls_drag).

I would imagine the first way is easier to implement as I had a lot of trouble trying to group the OBJ models this way previously (I think due to their associated MTL files preventing their material being of type Lambert).

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to identify the object by raycasting from the 'Shift-Click' event then you should be able to go up to the object's parent and remove it. The next animate frame will not draw it.

```
const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
if (intersects.length > 0) {
  const doomed = intersects[0].object;
  doomed.parent.remove(doomed);
}
```